# How to scan nested arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, layer

I would like to know how I can completely loop through an array (like with a foreach) in order to rearrange the data. However, this array contains arrays and those arrays contains arrays etc etc. For example :

```
$data= array(
               'key1' => array(
                   'key2' => 'value2', 
                   'key3' => 'value3'
                ),
                'key4' => array(
                   'key5' => 'value5', 
                   'key6' => 'value6'
                )
           )
```

In this example I know I could just use two foreach to loop through it and do the operation I need to rearrange the data but in my case I don't know how much arrays are nested in `$data` since I didn't made it and it is way too big for me to just take a look and count.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "scan"? Extract values? Count values? You probably will need a recursive function.

Comment: Your teacher harps on about recursion for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities.

You could use recursion:

```
function scan($array) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (is_array($item) {
            scan($item);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

or if you want to avoid recurstion, you could convert the recursion in a loop

```
function scan($array) {
    $stack = [$array];
    do {
        foreach (array_shift($stack) as $item) {
            if (is_array($item) {
                $stack[] = $item;
            }
            // ...
        }
    } while (count($stack) > 0);
}
```

or something different - depends on your needs

Answer (score 2):

You write your loop in a function that you can call if any of the children are an array, like so:

```
function checkArray($array, $value){
    foreach($array as $entry){
        if(is_array($entry)){ 
            checkArray($entry, $value); 
        } else {
            // Do your check and logic here.
        }
    }
}
$example = array( 'key' => array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'), 'key4' => 'value4');
checkArray($example, 'value4');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function for "scan" the arrays. This function will recurse into deeper arrays. You will get back every member of an array.

```
$arr = [[["element1", "element2", ["element3"]]],["element4"]];
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'test_print');
function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}
```